Tkinter gui widgets resized after including matlab plot function
I am trying to use a GUI for button and plot.
When I include show_graph() function inside tabss the window is resized, also widgets and text resized to smaller.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

# Function to toggle the motor button state
def togglebutton():
    if Controlbutton["text"] == "Disable":
        Controlbutton["text"] = "Enable"
        Controlbutton["bg"] = "orange"
    else:
        Controlbutton["text"] = "Disable"
        Controlbutton["bg"] = "red"

def show_graph(tab):
    spd_frame = Frame(tab)
    spd_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)

    time = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    speed = 3 * time + 2

    ax.plot(time, speed)
    ax.set_xlabel("X (s)")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y")

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=spd_frame)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().config(width=500, height=200)

# Function to create tabs and plot graphs
def tabss(root):
    # Tabs window
    tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(root)

    operationtab = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
    plottab = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)

    tabcontrol.add(operationtab, text='Operations')
    tabcontrol.add(plottab, text='Plot')
    tabcontrol.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    # Operation content START
    optframe = Frame(operationtab)
    optframe.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label(optframe, text="State:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    global Controlbutton
    Controlbutton = Button(optframe, text="Disable", command=togglebutton, bg="red", width=20, height=2)
    Controlbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=30)

    Label(optframe, text="Control Mode:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    tkvar = StringVar(optframe)
    ControlModeoptions = ["Open", "close"]
    ControlMode = OptionMenu(optframe, tkvar, *ControlModeoptions)
    ControlMode.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
    ControlMode.config(width=15)
    tkvar.set(ControlModeoptions)  # Set default value

    #show_graph(plottab)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Basic setting for main window
    root = Tk()
    root.title("GUI V0.1")
    root.geometry("880x600")

    # Call the function to create tabs and plots
    tabss(root)

    root.mainloop()

To resolve this I used

pack_propagate(False)


grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

without including show_graph function

after including show_graph GUI is resized to smaller
where should I configure to resolve this.
I ran both the code with and without show_graph function
bigger one is without show_graph function and smaller one is with show_graph function.


Post the screenshot when including show_graph(plottab) as I cannot reproduce the issue.  See my output.

Is the system scaling setting not set to 100%?

it is in 150%(Recommended). I also tried the 100%

I can reproduce the issue when my system scaling is set to 150%.  However, as said in my first comment, I cannot reproduce the issue when my system scaling is set to 100%.

My suggestion is
Don't use matplotlib.pyplot.figure for matplotlib 3.5.1, but matplotlib.figure.Figure to generate your figure.

As @JasonYang suggested I replaced

matplotlib.pyplot.figure

with

matplotlib.figure.Figure

It worked and no resize or scaling issue

there's a typo in your answer matploylib could you correct it to make it easier for other people to test and use your solution?
